# Yii2 Swiftmailier not working with Godaddy SMTP setting

Tags: php, yii2, smtp, swiftmailer

Swiftmailier Gmail SMTP is working every where but not on Godaddy hosting as they don't allow third party and they gave following settings

```
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
    'useFileTransport' => false,
    'transport' => [
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        Host = relay-hosting.secureserver.net
        Port = 25
        SMTPDebug = 0
        SMTPSecure =none 
        SMTPAuth = false
        Username = none
        Password = none
    ]
]
```

This configuration started sending emails but stopped now.

Errors are following:

- > undefined method "SMTPDebug "
- > undefined method "SMTPSecure "
- > undefined method "SMTPAuth "
- > Connection failed

I have tried almost everything, even approached Godaddy support but not getting any solution.

How can I set SMTPDebug  / SMTPSecure  / SMTPAuth these values in following configuration or how can my script start sending emails

Comment: Typo `Port = 25` should be `'port' => 25`

Comment: I have tried that but not working ... Any idea how to solve above mentioned errors?

Comment: @InsaneSkull Can you suggest anything? It is related to Godaddy

Comment: No experience with GoDaddy :(